# UIImageView not showing on first tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

```
-(void)tapCell:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
  CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:tableView];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
  if(indexPath.row == [appDelegate.users count]){
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"StartToCreateUser" sender:self];

}else if(indexPath){
    NSLog(@"ELSE IF TAP");
    NSLog(@"location: %f , %f", location.x, location.y);
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe_gray"];
    self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y+96+20);
    self.imageView.alpha = 1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 animations:^{self.imageView.alpha=0;}];
}
```

}

My problem is that on the first tap, the UIImageView is not showing. After the first tap everything works fine. The else if gets called on the first tap (so indexPath is NOT nil), the location is the same on each tap. UIImageView is just not showing on first tap. I am pulling hairs out, any help greatly appreciated!:)

Comment: Try to change place of `self.imageView.alpha = 1;` and `self.imageView.alpha = 0;`, when the animation completes, it should have an alpha vale 1.0.

Comment: @gabbler as I described it works after the first tap. The first tap does nothing, but second and so forth works fine. It doesn't make sense to switch the alphas. They are put intentionally, so the image will fade away after 1.2secs, as it does properly after.

Comment: Is the imageView visible before the first tap?

Comment: no, it doesn't get set before the first tap. another thing, I just noticed when running the app on a phone 7.0.1 (and not in the simulator). I don't see the picture at all when tapping; but i don't suppose any of these methods have been deprecated.

Comment: Try something like this: `[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0 delay: 0.2 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations: ^{ self.imageView.alpha = 0;}` hope that helps. Other question: where is your imageView initialised?

Comment: @anneblue that method also takes a parameter called completion. Anyway, that method has the same result as mine. imageView is declared as a property in the header-file. I tried do this    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe_gray"]]; before my if statement. And I tried self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:nil]; in viewDidLoad. Both result in my image  not showing at all when tapped (voodoo, but I don't think initialising like that is needed..?).

Comment: you're right, I've missed the completion parameter when copying it. Sorry for that. Hm. But where do you initialise your `UIImageView` now and where do you add it to your view hierarchy?

Comment: furthermore changing    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe_gray"];      TO     self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe_gray"]];    also makes image not showing. I still think my initial approach was fine, but I don't understand why this would make the image not showing at all

Comment: @anneblue sry I was unclear. Its declared as a property being an _IBOutlet_ as Im using IB

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your UITableViewController and explain where the UIImageView should appear?

Comment: @anneblue self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y+96+20);

Comment: I meant a IB screenshot...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66742/discussion-between-anneblue-and-devilindisguise).

Comment: it is working fine, just not at the first tap (and obv not in older versions of ios.. sadly), I don't see why it would be related to IB